# Use Existed DataBase with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm developin project using spring data jpa and spring mvc. I ask if it is possible to set as a parameter the name of the table specified within the annotation `@Table`. In fact,  I need every time to import data from different schema so I should specify the name of the table and their fields in the entity as parameters. Is it possible to do that with hibernate?

Comment: Yes, it is. This is what Hibernate is done for. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/

Comment: I think that you didn't understand me. the data base that i would to use contains already data So Ineed To specify in  a xml file the name of tables and files. THen i will unmarshall the xml file with jaxb into a java config  object.Finally I wish setting the name of the table representing each entity as a parameter and their fields after getting them from the config object.

Comment: Please be more specific :)

Comment: Ok @primitiveType. My goal is to allow the user of my application to deploy it even with existed data base. So I create a configuration  xml file where he can specify the  name of each table representing each entity as well as their fields  without touching the code.

Comment: OKay if there is a project (Which made in Spring and Not using Hibernate) and you want to to inject `Hibernate` functionality to it, just adding `hibernate.config.xml` (With all the tables and fields matching with exisitning DB) is not enough. You have to make use of Hibernate while getting a connection and data As well, You need to make lot of chnages in your Exisiting project.